# Symfony - set expiration time automatically

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4, getter-setter

I am setting new entity in my form and I have field 'created' which I want to use to set expiration time automatically. I want for expired field to be set on true 30 minutes after entity is set.

I have some logic created but I think it won't work.

My part of the code:

```
 $dateNow = new \DateTime();
    $entity->setCreated($dateNow)->modify("+33 Minutes");
    if($dateNow >= $entity){
        $entity->setExpired(true);
        $this->em->persist($entity);
        $this->em->flush();
    }

if($entity->isExpired()) {
        throw new /Exception('Sorry,it is expired.');
    }
```

Do you have any idea how to do this when using setter in Doctrine? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example you compare an DateTime instance with your entity which probably is another type and not a DateTime.

To find out, if your entity is expired, just compare the DateTime instance which is set as created with a new DateTime instance. You can use the diff() method. Probably it is not useful to store a flag in your database, but I don't know your usecase.

It could look similar to this (untestet):

```
<?php
//...
function isExpired() {
    $diff = $this->createdAt->diff(new DateTime());
    return $diff->i >= 30;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to correct the above answer `$diff->m` represents months, minutes is '**i**' so the correct code would be `$diff->i >= 30`

Comment: Sure! My mistake, sorry!